# gsap rotation - how to avoid sharp transitions

Tags: javascript, gsap

Could someone help me make this swing more fluently, without this sharp transitions from one direction to another? The animation should be like a swing on wind.

```js
const  stepDuration = 0.5, wing = '#wing';
gsap.set(wing, {transformOrigin: "50% 0%", rotation: 15})
const walk = () => {gsap.timeline({repeat: -1, defaults: { ease: "circ.inOut", duration: stepDuration }})
    .add('start')
 .to(wing, { rotation: -15 })
    .to(wing, { rotation: 15 })
}
window.onload = () => {walk()};
```

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  animation: a01 9s;
  background: #0099cc;
}

#wing {
  fill: gold;
  transform-origin: top center;
  animation: awinga 25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.0.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MotionPathPlugin.min.js?v=15"></script>

   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
      <path id='wing' d="M100 0 L150 0 L150 300 L100 300 Z" />
    </svg>

<script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is basically a tweening/easing function that tapers out at the start and at the end, without a sharp gradient in between. The reason of your jerking is because for the `circ.inOut` easing, there is basically an infinitesimally small period of time where the gradient is infinite (right at the 50% mark), which causes the sharp jerking you see when it's mid-tween (right when your element rotates past the vertical midline):

[image: circ.inOut has to steep transition]

Therefore, you should pick an easing function that doesn't have that abrupt change in the middle, e.g. `power1.inOut` or the likes of it:

[[image: power1.inOut has a gentler in-between gradient[2]]

```js
const  stepDuration = 0.5, wing = '#wing';
gsap.set(wing, {transformOrigin: "50% 0%", rotation: 15})
const walk = () => {gsap.timeline({repeat: -1, defaults: { ease: "power1.inOut", duration: stepDuration }})
    .add('start')
 .to(wing, { rotation: -15 })
    .to(wing, { rotation: 15 })
}
window.onload = () => {walk()};
```

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  animation: a01 9s;
  background: #0099cc;
}

#wing {
  fill: gold;
  transform-origin: top center;
  animation: awinga 25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.0.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MotionPathPlugin.min.js?v=15"></script>

   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
      <path id='wing' d="M100 0 L150 0 L150 300 L100 300 Z" />
    </svg>

<script>

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and especially thanks for the explanation. You saved my life. Is there any reference page about this params?

Comment: @qadenza Glad to help :)

Comment: @qadenza You can use GSAP's [Ease Visualizer](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Eases) to view eases like this.